# Why this json is throwing an error in IE console and in Visual studio screen parser?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-2010

I've been looking and looking I can't seem to figure why...

```
{
    "Head": 
    [{
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "Pete"
    }]
};
```

Throws an error in IE console and in visual studio screen parser with errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no semi-colon in JSON. You're describing data, not statements.

```
{
    "Head": 
    [{
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "Pete"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a JSON string, then the `;` is causing an error - remove it. JSON doesn't have `;`

If this is a JS object, it must be assigned to a variable somewhere.